# Cycling images using a thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I realize that there is A LOT of documentation when it comes to threading but I'm just starting to delve deeper into android development and I'm having a rather hard time understanding when to use the the certain threads.

In my case I am trying to cycle through drawable images with button presses. As there are a lot of images there is sometimes a delay with an error saying there is too much work on the main thread. I think I should be using runOnUiThread or AsyncTask or I am completely wrong.

Please don't flame me, Im just trying to get a deeper understanding of Android development.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: The only deep understanding you can get with threads or multi-threading is when you actually start something on it, from your quest i feel you already have what it takes to start a multi-thread, just new Thread() and you are done, or yeah use async task or whatever you choose but at the end of the day is you logic or your go-to way that is important.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you're right. Heavy time consuming operations should not be performed on the main thread. And `AsyncTask` should be used for this operation. You can load the images in doInBackground method and call your runOnUiThread method in onPostExecute method.

EDIT: [this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) would help you understand better. Follow this [android blog link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html) to dive deeper